# Given points on a circle, find the minimum number of points which can be separated with a line through the center

Tags: r, math, geometry, graph-algorithm, computational-geometry

Assume you are given a vector of degrees which represent points on the unit circle. How could you formally check to see what the minimum number of points you could isolate in one semicircle with a diameter? I understand there may be multiple diameters which satisfy this property for a given set of data points. That is okay. I am solely interested in the minimum number of points which can be isolated, not the diameter in particular. It also needs to be computationally efficient, so it works for a large number of points. I have written the following based on @d.b suggestion, but the algorithm fails for tst4.

In R,

```
# Plots the points on a circle and attempts to find the minimum m (algorithm incorrect for tst )
min_dia <- function(degs, plot = T){
  library(dplyr)

  plot_circle <- function(x, y, r) {
    angles <- seq(0, 2*pi,length.out = 360)
    lines(r*cos(angles) + x, r*sin(angles) + y)
  }

  deg <- degs
  plot_boo <- plot

 # @d.b suggestion method for finding m
  temp <- abs((deg - min(deg) + 180) %% 360 - 180)
  m <- min(table(cut(temp, breaks = c(-180, 90, 180))))

  if(plot_boo == T){
    tm_deg <- c(0, 30, 45, 60, 90, 120, 135, 150, 180, 210, 225, 240, 270, 300, 315, 330)
    tm_rad <- (tm_deg * pi) / 180
    th <- (deg*pi)/180
    r <- 1
    x <- r*cos(th)
    y <- r*sin(th)
    windows.options(width = 600, height = 600)
    plot(x, y, xlim = c(-1.1, 1.1), ylim = c(-1.1, 1.1), pch = 20, xlab = "", ylab = "", main = "Plot of Given Data Points by Degrees")
    plot_circle(0, 0, 1)
    points(0, 0)
    text(r*cos(tm_rad), r*sin(tm_rad), labels = paste0(tm_deg), cex= 0.5, pos = 3)
  }

  return(m)
}

# Function to plot diameter by degrees
plot_dia <- function(deg){
  deg1 <- deg
  deg2 <- deg + 180
  th1 <- (deg1*pi)/180
  th2 <- (deg2*pi)/180
  x1 <- cos(th1)
  y1 <- sin(th1)
  x2 <- cos(th2)
  y2 <- sin(th2)
  lines(c(x1, x2), c(y1, y2))
}

# Testing
tst1 <- c(15, 45, 20) # m = 0
tst2 <- c(15, 45, 200) # m = 1
tst3 <- c(15, 46, 114, 137, 165, 187, 195, 215, 271, 328) # m = 3
tst4 <- c(36, 304, 281, 254, 177, 59, 47, 158, 244, 149, 317, 235, 345, 209, 204,
          156, 325, 95, 215, 267)

# Implementation
min_dia(tst1)
plot_dia(90) # eyeball and plot to check

min_dia(tst2)
plot_dia(190) # eyeball and plot to check

min_dia(tst3)
plot_dia(110) # eyeball and plot to check

min_dia(tst4)
plot_dia(150) # m is probably 2
```

For the three points I have provided in the code with degrees 15, 45, and 225, the minimum number of points (say m) I could separate with a line would be 1.

For the points with degrees 15, 20, 25, the answer would obviously be 0.

Any help or guidance on an efficient algorithm to solve this minimization problem would be greatly appreciated.

Update:

Here is the plot if you were to run through the R code along with an example of a line which illustrates the minimum number of points you could separate, being 1.

[image: Example for degrees 15, 45, and 225]

Update:

I have also updated the code above which allows one to plot the data points, speculate a diameter which minimizes m, and the plot the diameter by degree.

Comment: I'm having trouble visualizing the problem...

Comment: I just uploaded a plot if you were to run the example. Does that help illustrate the problem? @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: So you want the points to be *approximately* distributed evenly across the center in each half?

Comment: Not particularly. I want to find the minimum number of points I can isolate in a half by splitting the circle in half. Does that help clarify the problem? @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: Wouldn't a line at 17 split the circle into 15, and 20 and 25?

Comment: It would indeed, but it wouldn't solve the minimization problem. Consider the line with degree 0 which passes through the center of the circle. It would create a semicircle with no points on one of the semicircles. Thus, m would be 0. @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: Ah, now I understand.

Comment: Can you please define "set apart"? Because in your example, I'm reading it as you need to have two lines for 3 points to be fully separated. Your image shows one line splitting 3 points. Unless I'm missing something, the number of lines to "separate" the points will always be 1, or to separate all of them its number of points minus 1.

Comment: @Kamil: There is always a single line. In some cases it is possible to have all points one side of the line (resulting in 0), whereas in some it is not.

Comment: You could sort these points by angle and, for each point, find the index / indices where the other half-line cuts the circle. This gives O(N log N) instead of O(N^2) for a brute-force approach. Not sure if this is doable in R though (at least in an elegant manner).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a brute force method. Just draw a line at all angle (`0.5:359.5`) and see what angle gives the least value.

```
bar = function(degs){
    CUTS = sapply(0:359 + 0.5, function(D){
        temp = ((degs - D + 180) %% 360 - 180)
        min(table(cut(temp, breaks = c(-180, 0, 180))))
    })

    D = (0:359 + 0.5)[which.min(CUTS)]
    m = min(CUTS)

    plot(0, 0, type = "n",
    xlim = c(-1.5, 1.5), ylim = c(-1.5, 1.5),
    ann = FALSE, axes = FALSE, asp = 1)
    plotrix::draw.circle(0, 0, 1)

    degs = degs * pi/180
    xs = cos(degs)
    ys = sin(degs)

    x1 = cos(D * pi/180)
    y1 = sin(D * pi/180)

    x2 = cos((D * pi/180) + pi)
    y2 = sin((D * pi/180) + pi)

    lines(c(x1, x2), c(y1, y2))
    points(xs, ys, pch = 19)
    points(0, 0)
    return(c(min_num = m, angle = D))
}

tst4 <- c(36, 304, 281, 254, 177, 59, 47, 158, 244, 149, 317, 235,
             345, 209, 204, 156, 325, 95, 215, 267)

bar(degs = tst4)
# min_num   angle 
#     5.0   145.5
```

[image]

Comment: While it may have worked for that particular example, it doesn't seem to work in general. @d.b When trying your solution with the given degrees: `deg <- c(15, 46, 114, 137, 165, 187, 195, 215, 271, 328)` it says m=2, but I believe it should result in m=3.

Comment: If you plot those degrees with the plotter I provided in the description, I don't see how you could possibly separate 2 points with any line through the center.

Comment: your algorithm fails tst 4. I have updated some code above. I am also working to try to implement MBo comments, but I am struggling with allocation. Any help with the R code for that would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If points are not sorted, then sort them by angle.

Walk through the list using two-pointer approach. Increment right index if angle difference is `<180`, increment left index if angle difference is `>180`. Minimum from `(right-left, length-right+left)` is your desired value.

Note that scanning should be performed in cyclic manner (you may add copy of the list with +360 addition like this `15, 45, 225, 375, 585`)

Comment: thank you for your detailed suggestion. Working on this now.